# RMarkdown: ggplot2で日本語を使用する

Tags: ggplot2

RMarkdownでPDFファイルを作成しています。`ggplot2`で日本語を表示させたいのですが、RStudio上では表示できる図が、PDFに変換した場合にはエラーとなります。

```
data %>% select_("Q1.4", "Group") %>%
    ggplot(aes(factor(Q1.4), fill=factor(Group))) + geom_bar() +
    coord_flip() + theme_gray(base_family="YuGo-Medium") +
    scale_fill_hue(name = "Group") + labs(x="Choice") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("NA",5,4,3,2,1),
        labels=c("NA", "全く思わない", "あまり思わない",
        "どちらとも思わない","やや思う","思う"))
```

このコードは、RStudio上では動作し、日本語を含む図が作成されます。しかし、PDFを作ろうとすると、

```
> rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd')
Quitting from lines 115-125 (test.Rmd)
 grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  でエラー:
   フォントタイプが不正です
 呼び出し:  <Anonymous> ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
 追加情報:  50 件以上の警告がありました (最初の 50 個の警告を見るには warnings() を使って下さい)
```

となって、PDFファイルを作成できません。いくつかの解決法も試して見ましたが、同じエラーが発生しました。([１](http://qiita.com/uri/items/615653e83642d7e475de#%E8%BB%B8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86), [２](http://qiita.com/kazutan/items/1f9da9ba2d83db26f3ad))

RMarkdownの設定は、

```
---
title: 'Analysis'
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
 pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
  fig_width: 4.0
  fig_height: 2.8
  number_sections: true
  toc: true
  toc_depth: 2
graphics: yes
mainfont: YuMincho
---
```

Rについては以下の通りです。

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R が認識できるフォントはたとえば，`Japan1GothicBBB` とか `Japan1Ryumin` なので，これを指定するか。あるいは，Mac であれば `quartz()` デバイスを使うとよいようです。[参考](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/stat/first.html)

したがって，コードチャンクを以下のようにすればよいと思います：

````
```{r, dev = "pdf", dev.args = list(family = "Japan1Ryumin"), warning=FALSE}
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_point() + 
  xlab("気温") + ylab("気圧") + 
  theme_gray()
```
````

あるいは

````
```{r, dev="quartz_pdf", warning=FALSE}
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + geom_point() + 
  xlab("気温") + ylab("気圧") +
  theme_gray(base_family = "YuGo-Medium")
```
````

`warning=FALSE` を指定しないとたくさん警告がでますが，正しく出力されます。[このコメント](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/436#issuecomment-11757370)で述べられている振る舞いに関係があるのかもしれません（未確認です）。

ところで，YAML ヘッダに `monofont: Ricty Discord` といった行を追加して等幅日本語フォントの指定をしておかないと，コードブロックの日本語が表示されません。